# How to make such cogwheel in 2.82?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I am watching a video for tank track, and now i have reached to the drive wheel. It needs to have pointy surface in order to move the tracks. The guy in the [video](https://youtu.be/q5fjslhomsI?t=696) made a circle, selected all vertices and then used "Checker Deselect" to select vertex, then skip one and so on. Then he scaled it down, making something like a sun. But when i try to scale, it doesnt even move. I tried with move and rotate, i tried to extrude, but still no result. Does anyone know how can i do this?

Comment: so your problem is that you can't scale down a selection of vertices? Have you set your pivot point to Median Point for example?

Comment: @moonboots Ok that helped! Im still quite new to blender, thats why my mistake is stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i try to scale, it doesnt even move.

You can scale with the scale tool - press and release <kbd>alt</kbd> and then <kbd>s</kbd>, or select in the tool panel:
[image]

Or you can just hit <kbd>s</kbd> to use interactive scale operator.

You should also make sure you have the correct selection and that you are using the transform pivot that you want, that you can select here:

[image]

Comment: Love the size of the red arrow. :)